# Intro to Python: How to ask the user if they want to repeat the for loop?

Tags: python, loops

I need help figuring out how to ask the user if they would like to repeat the program. Any help is much appreciated. I am relatively new to Python and it would be great to receive some advice!

```
X = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter? "))

Sum = 0
sumNeg = 0
sumPos = 0
for i in range(0,X,1):
    number = float(input("Please enter number %i : " %(i+1) ))

    # add every number to Sum
    Sum = Sum + number # Sum += number

    #only add negative numbers to sumNeg
    if number < 0:
        sumNeg += number # sumNeg = sumNeg + number
    #only add positive numbers to sumPos
    if number > 0:
        sumPos += number # sumPos = sumPos + number

print ("------")

print ("The sum of all numbers = ", Sum)
print ("The sum of negative numbers = ", sumNeg)
print ("The sum of positive numbers = ", sumPos)
```

I'm not sure if I need to use a while loop, but how would I enter a (y/n) into my code because I am asking for an integer from the user in the beginning.

Comment: You can try these 2 small improvements. `range(X)` should work. No need to specify start and step because you you use the default values.
You can use `elif number > 0`. The result will be the same but Python - for a negative number - won't even evaluate the second condition.

Comment: Also by convention it's better not use upper case in your variable names. Example use `sum_neg` (or even `sumneg` if you prefer) instead of `SumNeg`. Have a look [here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) for Python naming convention.

Comment: @0x0fba Thank you for your advice, but how I would ask the user if they would like to restart the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have an outer loop that comprises your whole processing.
It's an infinite loop.
You exit from this loop thanks to the `break` statement once the user has answered no.
In fact once he has answered everything else than `Y` or `y`. The user string is converted to `lower()` before comparison for more convenience.

```py
while True:
    X = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter? "))
    Sum = 0
    sumNeg = 0
    sumPos = 0
    for i in range(0, X, 1):
        number = float(input("Please enter number %i : " % (i + 1)))

        # add every number to Sum
        Sum = Sum + number  # Sum += number

        # only add negative numbers to sumNeg
        if number < 0:
            sumNeg += number  # sumNeg = sumNeg + number
        # only add positive numbers to sumPos
        if number > 0:
            sumPos += number  # sumPos = sumPos + number

        print("------")

        print("The sum of all numbers = ", Sum)
        print("The sum of negative numbers = ", sumNeg)
        print("The sum of positive numbers = ", sumPos)

    resp = input("Would you like to repeat the program  ? (y/n)")
    if resp.lower() != "y":
        break
```

As an alternative to the `while True` loop.
You could declare at the top of the script a variable `user_wants_to_play = True`.
The while statement becomes `while user_wants_to_play`.
And set the variable to `False` when the user answers no.

Comment: Close, but the problem is the for loop is supposed to allow the user to enter as many numbers as they like, but you're printing under an if.

Comment: It wasn't quite clear in your question. I guess you don"t want a **play again mode** (just repeat the program ).
Do you want to ask the user if he'd like to continue **adding numbers to the same total** ?

Comment: I got it, I just printed after the for loop and it worked. Thank you very much for your help. You've done plenty!

Answer (score 1):

Ask the user for input at the end of the loop to continue or not. If the user doesn't want to continue, use a break statement to break out of the loop.

[https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/break-in-python#:~:text='Break'%20in%20Python%20is%20a,condition%20triggers%20the%20loop's%20termination](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/break-in-python#:%7E:text=%27Break%27%20in%20Python%20is%20a,condition%20triggers%20the%20loop%27s%20termination).

Answer (score 0):

The following program will keep on executing until user enter 0 to break the loop.

```
while True: 
    X = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter? "))
    Sum, sumNeg, sumPos = 0
    for i in range(X):
        number = float(input("Please enter number %i : " %(i+1) ))
        Sum += number
        if number < 0:
            sumNeg += number
        if number > 0:
            sumPos += number
    print ("------")
    
    print ("The sum of all numbers = ", Sum)
    print ("The sum of negative numbers = ", sumNeg)
    print ("The sum of positive numbers = ", sumPos)
        
    print ("------")
    trigger = int(input("The close the program enter 0: "))
        
    if trigger == 0:
        break
```